# Datagridview don't display items

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

hi I have a somewhat bizarre problem
When I go to add the table from sql on datagridview like:

```
Dim Connection As New SqlConnection("SERVER=*******;DATABASE=********;USER=sa;PWD=********")

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query1, Connection)

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    Dim commandbuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

    Dim ds = New DataSet()

    da.Fill(ds)

    dtgMain.AutoGenerateColumns = True

    dtgMain.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Nothing is displayed in the datagridview.
If I count the rows and columns imported:

```
   MsgBox(dtgMain.Columns.Count)

    MsgBox(dtgMain.Rows.Count)
```

It correctly returns both.
Even if I preview the ds.tables I can see the table correctly

Tips??

Comment: Try `dtgMain.Refresh()` after setting the `DataSource property`.

Comment: If this code is in form load event sometimes there can be an exception which does not get thrown, try moving the code if in form load event to the form shown event. Also, try removing the DataGridView and then add a new one back in to ensure there is no corruption and/or some property is set that may be interfering with showing data.

Comment: Trivial: is the CellStyle ForeColor set to the same Color as the BackGround? Data related: You say you have Rows and Columns, but what is the Cells' Value? Did you inspect that? UI related: did you create Columns in the designer? Do you see *blank* Rows or the DGV's standard gray-ish background (or whatever color you assigned to the property)? Is this the first time you set the DataSource?

Comment: @Dan doesn't work

Comment: @Karen it is not on a loading form but on a private function called by a form mdi for filters. (I have already checked the integrity of the data that is passed by the mdi form). I have already tried deleting datagridview and reinserted it. Does not work

Comment: @Jimi I have inspected the cell value, it is correct. I have already reported it in previous programs using the same code always in datagridview. I see the standard gray background of the dgv. I tried to create empty columns while running the code and they are not replaced. It is as if there is no refresh after the import.
I have been working with DGV for almost a year and have never had such problems

Comment: Then: 1) You are not looking at the actual DataGridView object you see on a Form: meaning, you have used `FormX form = new FormX()` to access the DataGridView object in a Form, thus the original DGV is never filled (this is a classic). 2) You don't see the Cells' content because the ForeColor is the same as the BackgroundColor (this is common but easy to spot, simply selecting a Cell).

Comment: @Jimi
1) now that I think about it while passing the data, I also call the function (of parent form) to execute the sql query, perhaps this is the problem. I tried to insert it on the form_closing event of the mdi form but nothing yet. I have no idea how to start it automatically once I close the mdi form, my friend. do you have ideas?
2) I tried to set a code forecolor for security, it doesn't work